# Measurability of composition of random vector w.r.t. $\sigma$(X)

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Here is a problem from Resnick - Probability Path (3.3) :

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^k) / \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}) $.

Let also $X_1,...,X_k$ be random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr{B}) $ .

Show that $f(X_1,...,X_k) \in \sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$ (which I guess it is as saying that $f$ is measurable w.r.t. the sigma algebra generated by the random vector X).

I think that it would be enough to show that $\sigma(f(X_1,...,X_k)) \subset \sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$, (with $\sigma(f(X)) =${$X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B)):B\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}) $} , if I'm not wrong); but I don't know how to prove it.
Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Then $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^k)$, and thus $$f(X_1,...,X_k)^{-1}(B)=(X_1,...,X_k)^{-1}(f(B))\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^k).$$

Done.

Comment: But how can you apply $(X_1,...,X_k)$ on B?

Comment: @AkaiM: I dont understand your question.

Comment: I mean, since $B = f(X(\omega))$, how can you compute $f(X^{-1}(B))$? So how can you apply the inverse image of X on the image of the composition f(X)?

Comment: $B\neq f(X)$ @AkaiM

Comment: Isn't it
$$
f(X_1,...,X_k)^{-1}(B)=(X_1,...,X_k)^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))\in \mathscr B?
$$